# PHP and ActiveRecord: How to handle multiple table with one controller

Tags: php, mysql, rails-activerecord

I guys i am playing around with Active Record for PHP(php-activerecord from composer/packagist).

I am building an application where once the user register a new table with his username will be created.

Assuming that 1000 users will register to my application 1000 tables will be created, but all the tables will be of the same type(structure?), should i instead use one table and put everything in?.

And if create 1000 tab do i need to create 1000 models? Is there a way to tell active record to handle all those tables of the same type with one model?

Please let me know if i confuse you i'll try to explain better.

Thanks

Comment: One table for each user?

Comment: I know it sounds crazy, but this is my first hosted app and is the first time i have this kind of problem

Comment: One table per user is a terrible idea. Don't do it.

Comment: Yep. Make it 1 row per user.

Comment: Please read: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/119352/does-the-activerecord-pattern-follow-encourage-the-solid-design-principles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can handle multiple tables in a single model.
It is a good practice to put logically related querying into the same model.
The primary question why do need 1000 tables why not create 1000 rows?

Comment: Well, imagine to build a To-Do list application where every users will insert 10,20...100 items every day put everything in one table will create quickly a huge one. And what if the users instead of 1000 are 10.000 or 100.000 etc. Does mysql can manage this sort of size in one table?

Comment: According to the need you specified it better to do what you are suggesting. It better you do all that tables in one model.

Comment: As another example take facebook, big number of users and every user type everyday massages on their personal page, the messages are of the same structure for all the user but will be to big to put all the messages of all the users in one table or i am wrong?

Comment: I do get your point. Create table for all user and have table which has the userid and tablename for all the users.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but now i am back to my original question, how do i do this(Code)? I checked the documentation but didn't find anything useful for this. I am reading an article now for something similar but is for active Record on rails

Comment: You can post the userid and retrieve the tablename from the commmon table. Using this table name i think you can do the following using php and codeigniter
$tablename=`$_POST['usertable']`;
`$this->db->select('*'); 
$query = $this->db->from ( $tablename );
`

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try that. Still is not clear how i define one model for multiple tables but i am still searching

Comment: What mvc application are you using?

Comment: plain php with php-activerecord